# Is it possible to make a macro sensitive to \\?

Tags: macros

I have the following macro:

```
   \newcommand{\INFERRULE}[3][]{%
   \ensuremath{\inferrule{\mathstrut #2}{\mathstrut #3}\ifx\\#1\\\else\enskip(#1)\fi}}
```

I want to make it sensitive to `\\` so that I can write commands such as:

```
   \[
   \INFERRULE[i \to j]{[i, i, j, k] \\ [i, k, j, j]}{[i, i, k, j]}
   \]
```

However, the way I defined the macro, it is ignoring the `\\`. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I tried using a begin{array} environment instead, but it seems like the inferrule does not let me do that?

Comment: @kloop: can you please mention what package provides `\inferrule`: the answer will depend on what that command does? (or, even better, provide a full minimal working example, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending at `\end{document}`)

Comment: I managed to fix that by using begin{array} inside and \cr instead of \\. (apparently \\ is \crcr which does not work but just one \cr works.) thank you all!

Comment: In fact, LaTeX changes the definition of ``\\`` in various circumstances, to make it work like a line break as often as possible. Within an array environment ``\\`` can more or less be replaced by `\cr`, but not for everything.

Comment: To answerers: I think `\inferrule` comes from the [`mathpartir`](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/mathpartir.html) package. @kloop: It might help if you explain what you want the output to look like, as well as what you want to write in source.

Comment: @kloop maybe `$$\mprset {sep=6em}
 \inferrule {a \\ bbb} {cc}$$`?

Comment: @kloop: If your problem is fixed now, please post your solution as answer and accept it so that the question is marked as answered. Otherwise it will stay "unanswered" forever. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if you're still interested in an answer, but assuming the following things about your question:

- You are using the [`mathpartir`](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/) package which provides the `\inferrule` macro
- You would like to have multi-line premises

it seems easy to do.  The `mathpartir` documentation says

> A newline can be forced by adding an empty line `\\\\`
>
> ```
> \inferrule {aa \\\\ bb} {dd \\ ee \\ ff}
> ```

Since your `\INFERRULE` is a just a wrap-around for `\inferrule` you can do the same thing.  Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\newcommand{\INFERRULE}[3][]{%
\ensuremath{\inferrule{\mathstrut #2}{\mathstrut #3}\ifx\\#1\\\else\enskip(#1)\fi}}
\begin{document}
\[
   \INFERRULE[i \to j]
        {[i, i, j, k] \\ [i, k, j, j]}
        {[i, i, k, j]}
\]
\[
    \INFERRULE[i \to j]
        {[i, i, j, k] \\\\ [i, k, j, j]}
        {[i, i, k, j]}
\]    
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]